# Python Redis Sort() storing the output

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis

So, I'm trying to store the output a redis sort function into a variable.
I can't directly use 
`var = redis.sort(~something~)` 
because I'm using a pipeline that waits to execute

I've tried `redis.sort(name, store=var)` to no avail

```
    sorted_posts = None

    with r.pipeline() as pipe:
        pipe.multi()
        pipe.sadd('temp_posts', *post_id_list)
        pipe.sort(name='temp_posts', by='*->karma', get='*->post_id', desc=True, store=sorted_posts)
        pipe.delete('temp_posts')
        pipe.execute()

    print(sorted_posts)
    return sorted_posts
```

I'm not quite sure how to use the store option.
I was wondering if anyone else knew.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding how it works. It's storing the output in variable *inside* of Redis. It would look like this. Take a look at the [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/sort#storing-the-result-of-a-sort-operation) to get a better understanding.

```
key = 'sorted_posts'

with r.pipeline() as pipe:
        pipe.multi()
        pipe.sadd('temp_posts', *post_id_list)
        pipe.sort(name='temp_posts', by='*->karma', get='*->post_id', desc=True, store=key)
        pipe.delete('temp_posts')
        pipe.execute()

print(redis.get(key))
```